# Convert milliseconds into day,hour,minute and second iOS?

Tags: ios, date, date-arithmetic

I need to convert an milliseconds into Days, Hours, Minutes Second.

ex: 5 Days, 4 hours, 13 minutes, 1 second.

Thanks

Comment: Please search before posting.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: let totalSeconds : Double = Double(totalSeconds)
       
        let days = Int(floor(totalSeconds / (60*60*24)))
        var remainingSeconds = totalSeconds % (60*60*24)
        
        
        let hours =  Int(floor(remainingSeconds / (60*60)))
        remainingSeconds = remainingSeconds % (60*60)
        
        let minutes = Int(floor(remainingSeconds / (60)))
        remainingSeconds = remainingSeconds % (60)
        
        let seconds = Int(floor(remainingSeconds))
    
        print("seconds : \(seconds) minutes : \(minutes) hours : \(hours) days : \(days)")

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to do the calculation by yourself, you could go for such a solution.

I, however, know that is a kinda costly solution, so you need to be aware of potential performance issues in runtime – depending on how frequently you intend to invoke this.

---

```
NSTimeInterval _timeInSeconds = 123456789.123; // or any other interval...;

NSCalendar *_calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSCalendarUnit _units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
NSDateComponents *_components = [_calendar components:_units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:_timeInSeconds] options:kNilOptions];

NSLog(@"%ld Days, %ld Hours, %ld Minutes, %ld Seconds", _components.day, _components.hour, _components.minute, _components.second);
```

Comment: we get 14116 Days, 16 Hours, 0 Minutes, 0 Seconds result. please check hour. if hour greter then above 12 then add days 1. do you uderstand my problem.

Comment: I'm afraid to mention but... one day has 24 hours (not 12!), therefore the hours will be in interval `[0-23]`, and according to that having 16-hours is perfectly valid; or what do you think about how many hours a regular day has on planet Earth?

Comment: How about my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own function like this:

```
import UIKit

let miliseconds: Int = 24 * 3600 * 1000 + 3700 * 1000
// 1 day and 1 hour 1 minute 40 seconds

func convertTime(miliseconds: Int) -> String {

    var seconds: Int = 0
    var minutes: Int = 0
    var hours: Int = 0
    var days: Int = 0
    var secondsTemp: Int = 0
    var minutesTemp: Int = 0
    var hoursTemp: Int = 0

    if miliseconds < 1000 {
        return ""
    } else if miliseconds < 1000 * 60 {
        seconds = miliseconds / 1000
        return "\(seconds) seconds"
    } else if miliseconds < 1000 * 60 * 60 {
        secondsTemp = miliseconds / 1000
        minutes = secondsTemp / 60
        seconds = (miliseconds - minutes * 60 * 1000) / 1000
        return "\(minutes) minutes, \(seconds) seconds"
    } else if miliseconds < 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 {
        minutesTemp = miliseconds / 1000 / 60
        hours = minutesTemp / 60
        minutes = (miliseconds - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000 / 60
        seconds = (miliseconds - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 - minutes * 60 * 1000) / 1000
        return "\(hours) hours, \(minutes) minutes, \(seconds) seconds"
    } else {
        hoursTemp = miliseconds / 1000 / 60 / 60
        days = hoursTemp / 24
        hours = (miliseconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000 / 60 / 60
        minutes = (miliseconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000 / 60
        seconds = (miliseconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 - minutes * 60 * 1000) / 1000
        return "\(days) days, \(hours) hours, \(minutes) minutes, \(seconds) seconds"
    }
}

convertTime(miliseconds)
//result is "1 days, 1 hours, 1 minutes, 40 seconds"
```

Comment: See the picture, I don't know why you say this won't work??

Comment: It won't work because there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, not 100.

Comment: that does not care about the _days_ or _hours_ which the OP has requested.

Comment: Aw, I forgot 1 second is equal to 1000 miliseconds not 100 as I though =)). But the function is right, I just write a sample code for him to know, the hours and the days are much similar with those.

Comment: But I will update the answer soon, just give me 10 minutes.

Comment: Hey guys, see the updates :)

Answer (score 1):

I have write the easy code to do this in both Objective-c and Swift:

**Swift**

```
    var milliseconds : double_t =  568569600;

    milliseconds =  floor(milliseconds/1000);
    let seconds : double_t = fmod(milliseconds, 60);
    let minutes  : double_t = fmod((milliseconds / 60) , 60);
    let hours  : double_t = fmod((milliseconds / (60*60)), 60);
    let days : double_t = fmod(milliseconds / ((60*60)*24), 24);


    NSLog("seconds : %.f minutes : %.f hours : %.f days : %.f", seconds, minutes, hours, days);
```

Output - seconds : 9 minutes : 56 hours : 38 days : 7

**Objective**

```
        double milliseconds =  568569600;

    milliseconds =  milliseconds/1000;
    float seconds = fmod(milliseconds, 60);
    float minutes = fmod((milliseconds / 60) , 60);
    float hours = fmod((milliseconds / (60*60)), 60);
    float days = fmod(milliseconds / ((60*60)*24), 24);


    NSLog(@"seconds : %.f minutes : %.f hours : %.f days : %.f ", seconds, minutes, hours, days);
```

Output - seconds : 10 minutes : 56 hours : 38 days : 7

Comment: This isn't correct.  All you are doing is converting millisecs to seconds *then* minutes *then* hours etc.  The object is to breakdown millisecs to day/hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: i have updated the code. So, can you pls try now?

Comment: That does look better.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thankq :)

Comment: let hours  : double_t = fmod(milliseconds / (60*60), 60) >= 24 ? fmod(milliseconds / (60*60), 60) - 24 : fmod(milliseconds / (60*60), 60) i think we should use this for hours

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
NSTimeInterval time = <timein ms>;

NSInteger  days = time / (24 * 60 * 60);
NSInteger hours =  (time / (60 * 60)) - (24 * days);
NSInteger minutes =(time / 60) - (24 * 60 * days) - (hours * 60);
NSInteger seconds = (lroundf(time) % 60);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `time = <timein ms> / 1000;`?

Comment: sorry sorry I have updated the code

Comment: I can't see how that code works at all.  Why `- (24 * days);`?  What is the significance of 24 days?

Comment: thanks NSTimeInterval is by default in seconds

Comment: and yet you multiply it by `days`?  Have you tested the code?

Comment: yes as we have to minus the number of hours on that number of days

Comment: You'll need to be using the modulo operator quite alot...

Comment: with all respect NSTimeInterval is double we can't use modulo, we can lose precision

Comment: `NSTimeInterval`counts seconds so you can just cast it to `long` and lose the *fraction of a second* that it holds, given the OP just wants second accuracy.

Comment: ok sir I didn't know about required accuracy